# How to Upload Multiple Image in Rails 4 Using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, image-gallery

I am trying to create a gallery of Images for my Markets controller here I am able to to use paperclip to upload single image .I search on google but I haven't find any solution . How can I upload multiple images and show it in the form of gallery using paperclip . is there any way . Please suggest me the answer .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here is the article](https://web.archive.org/web/20181112003148/http://www.railscook.com/recipes/multiple-files-upload-with-nested-resource-using-paperclip-in-rails/), which explains in details, how to achieve it.
Some code snippets from there are below.

Models:

```
# app/models/market.rb
class Market < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, dependent: :destroy
end

# app/models/picture.rb
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :market

  has_attached_file :image,
    path: ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:filename",
    url: "/images/:id/:filename"

  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
end
```

View:

```
# app/views/markets/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @market, html: { class: "form-horizontal", multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :pictures, class: "control-label" %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <%= link_to t(".cancel", default: t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                galleries_path, class: "btn btn-mini" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
# app/controllers/markets_controller.rb
def create
  @market = Market.new(market_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @market.save

      if params[:images]
        params[:images].each { |image|
          @market.pictures.create(image: image)
        }
      end

      format.html { redirect_to @market, notice: "Market was successfully created." }
      format.json { render json: @market, status: :created, location: @market }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @market.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How do you add validations?

Comment: @liroy I think by [adding validations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#validations) to `Picture` model.

Comment: Hey I am unable to save image will you please explain how can i show that images . It is not getting saved under public/image

Comment: Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError in HousesController#create
what to do ?

Comment: @Nischaynamdev google the error to see possible solutions? :) I haven't met this error before, so won't tell for sure what to do unfortunately.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko i tried but do not found any solution.. actually  its showing error, Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError  and rails is pointing out to create method of market model.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110469/how-to-upload-multiple-image-in-rails-4-using-paperclip   link to follow... that's what I am implimenting.. can u see