# Ruby on Rails: Help in multiple image upload using paperclip with different process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip

I have 3 models: `Post`, `Comment,` and `Image`

(I am using paperclip gem BTW)

What I am trying to achieve is that users can comment on post.
Also, if they opt to comment images in the post, they could do so. The relationship looks like this:

For Post

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

For Comment

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :images, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

and for Image

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :comment
end
```

The process is that for example, they would like to comment on a post, and would like to attach an image, they could do so by attaching an image to the comment. They could also attach multiple image in one comment.

However, I can't seem to know how to do that. Upon researching, I stumbled this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110469/how-to-upload-multiple-image-in-rails-4-using-paperclip) which upload multiple images in a gallery.

However, it is only two layer model (Gallery and Picture). He makes use of this code in his view and controller:

View

```
<%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
```

controller

```
if params[:images]
  params[:images].each { |image|
    @market.pictures.create(image: image)
  }
end
```

I get on how to do that. But it is different from what I'm trying to achieve. If you can help me, that would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `accepts_nested_attribues_for` is what you're looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535748/nested-paperclip-form-with-multiple-images

Comment: What does your controller look like? Is it currently the same as the example you cited? If you can get it to work with one image, you might only need a small change to support multiple images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there may be different approach to upload but i would like to prefer this approach here with `nested attributes` and [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) here you can get an [example](https://www.hnhdigitalagency.com/blogs/using-nested-attributes-cocoon-paperclip-for-awesome-file-uploads-in-rails)